# How to assign a user in jira to log bugs only

Tags: jira

I am using Jira in my company. I want to give permission for a user where he can log only bugs but couldn't see all the other communication. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a project for bugs only, for example.
Then create a role, like "buglogger", and on permission schemas of each project, set permissions depending on a role. 
On your new bug project, your new buglogger users, should have almost all permissions, and on the other projects none.